# Join dataframe value series to another on datetime range from 1st dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, slice

I am trying to retrieve values from a dataframe (df2) that fall within a datetime range that is specified in another dataframe (df1).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range("20180101", periods=5)}, index=list('ABCDE'))
df1['t-2'] = df1['date'] + dt.timedelta(days=-2)
df1['t+2'] = df1['date'] + dt.timedelta(days=2)
```

df1:

```
        date        t-2        t+2
A 2018-01-01 2017-12-30 2018-01-03
B 2018-01-02 2017-12-31 2018-01-04
C 2018-01-03 2018-01-01 2018-01-05
D 2018-01-04 2018-01-02 2018-01-06
E 2018-01-05 2018-01-03 2018-01-07
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 50)), 
                   index=list('ABCDE'), columns = pd.date_range("20171201", periods=50))
```

df2:

```
      2017-12-01  2017-12-02  2017-12-03  ...  2018-01-17  2018-01-18  2018-01-19
A          58          61          45  ...          72          77          68
B          88          94          68  ...          93          68          24
C          97          47          21  ...          22          48          89
D          44           8          62  ...          57          29          29
E           0          21          26  ...          65          46          36
```

I would like to take the 5 cells from df2 that fall between the dates in df1 t-2 & t+2 & append these to df1 so that it looks like the following:

```
        date        t-2        t+2  t-2d  t-1d   t  t+1d  t+2d
A 2018-01-01 2017-12-30 2018-01-03    21    28  25     7     6
B 2018-01-02 2017-12-31 2018-01-04    28    25   7     6    45
C 2018-01-03 2018-01-01 2018-01-05    25     7   6    45    74
D 2018-01-04 2018-01-02 2018-01-06     7     6  45    74    23
E 2018-01-05 2018-01-03 2018-01-07     6  45    74    23    57
```

So far I have tried any number of combinations of the following

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.loc[:, df1['t-2']:df1['t+2']], how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but i receive a TypeError. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [A   2017-12-30
B   2017-12-31
C   2018-01-01
D   2018-01-02
E   2018-01-03
Name: t-2, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type Series
```

Comment: in your expected output, there is no line for `B 2018-01-01 2017-12-30 2018-01-03 ... ... ... ... ...`, but only a line that starts with `A`. Did you intentionally skip that? If so, what's the logic of keeping `A` but not `B` for `date=2018-01-01`?

Comment: Hi Raymond, expected output is as you describe and should cover rows A to E.